# Erro while installing dependencies from Botonic

Tags: react-native, npm, dependencies, npm-install, npm-package

I was installing a framework called Botonic and i installed perfectly but when I run the
command “botonic new my Bot blank” I get a huge NPM ERR! When it's time to install my dependencies.

```
~Jhenriqueax: botonic new myBot blank
✔ Downloading files...
✖ Installing dependencies...
Your message must be < 32kb. This is currently surfaced as a warning to allow clients to update. Versions released after August 1, 2018 will throw an error instead. Please update your code before then. {
  event: 'Error Botonic CLI',
  anonymousId: 87047954,
  properties: {
    platform: 'darwin',
    arch: 'arm64',
    timezone: 'America/Fortaleza',
    timestamp: '2023-01-18T21:45:38.995Z',
    is_tty: true,
    framework_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@botonic/cli/lib',
    system_path: '/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jhenriqueax/Development/flutter/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin',
    node_version: 'v16.14.2',
    botonic_cli_version: '0.20.2',
    botonic_dependencies: [ [Array] ],
    error_type: 'Installing dependencies: Error: Command failed: CXXFLAGS="--std=c++14" npm install\n' +
      'npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated\n' +
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade the node version to 14.16.1

1. If you're using nvm, try `nvm install 14.16.1`.
2. Then `use nvm 14.16.1`

Make sure you're npm version should be 6.14.12